# Regarding two lines of java code

Tags: java

I am trying to learn a java-based program, but I am pretty new to java. I am quite confusing on the following two lines of java code. I think my confusion comes from the concepts including “class” and “cast”, but just do not know how to analyze.

For this one

```
XValidatingObjectCorpus<Classified<CharSequence>> corpus
        = new XValidatingObjectCorpus<Classified<CharSequence>>(numFolds);
```

What is `<Classified<CharSequence>>` used for in terms of Java programming? How to understand its relationships with `XValidatingObjectCorpus`and `corpus`

For the second one

```
LogisticRegressionClassifier<CharSequence> classifier
            = LogisticRegressionClassifier.<CharSequence>train(para1, para2, para3)
```

How to understand the right side of `LogisticRegressionClassifier.<CharSequence>train`? What is the difference between `LogisticRegressionClassifier.<CharSequence>train` and `LogisticRegressionClassifier<CharSequence> classifier`
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are called [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). They tell Java to make an instance of the outer class - either `XValidatingObjectCorpus` or `LogisticRegressionClassifier` - using the type of the inner object.

Normally, these are used for lists and arrays, such as [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

### What is the relationship between `XValidatingObjectCorpus` and `corpus`?

`corpus` is just a name given to the new `XValidatingObjectCorpus` object that you make with that statement (hence the `= new...` part).

### What does `LogisticRegressionClassifier.<CharSequence>train` mean?

I have no idea, really. I suggest [looking at the API](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/docs/api/com/aliasi/classify/LogisticRegressionClassifier.html#toString%28%29) for that (I think this is the right class).

### What is the difference between `LogisticRegressionClassifier.<CharSequence>train` and `LogisticRegressionClassifier<CharSequence> classifier`?

You can't really compare these two. The one on the left of the `=` is the object *identifier*, and the one on the right is the *allocator* (probably the wrong word, but it is what it does, kind of).

Together, the two define an instance of `LogisticRegressionClassifier`, saying to create that type of object, call it `classifier`, and then give it the value returned by the `train()` method. Again, look at the API to understand it more.

By the way, these look like wretched examples to be learning Java with. Start with something simple, or at least an easier part of the code. It looks like someone had way too much fun with long names (the API has even longer names). Seriously though, I only just got to fully understanding this, and Java was my main language for quite a while (It gets really confusing when you try and do simple things). Anyways, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

- `<Classified<CharSequence>>` is a generic parameter.
- `LogisticRegressionClassifier<CharSequence>` is a generic type.
- `LogisticRegresstionClassifier.<CharSequence>train` is a generic method.

[Java Generics Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Comment: you missed the period in `.<CharSequence>train` on the last one. And `classifier` is an instance, not a type.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Sample<T> { // T implies Generic implementation, T can be substituted with any object. 

    static <T> Sample<T> train(int par1, int par2, int par3){
        return new Sample<T>(); // you are calling the Generic method to return Sample object which works with a particular type of generic object, may it be an Integer or a CharSequence. --> see the main method.

    }

    public static void main(String ... a)
    {
        int par1 = 0, par2 = 0, par3 = 1;
// Here you are returning Sample object which works with a sequence of characters.
        Sample<CharSequence> sample = Sample.<CharSequence>train(par1, par2, par3);
// Here you are returning Sample object which works with Integer values.
        Sample<CharSequence> sample1 = Sample.<Integer>train(par1, par2, par3);


    }

}
```

Comment: This made it more confusing because they aren't the real methods for the class. Also, it just says what a generic is, and doesn't really answer the question at hand.